# Amenability with respect to a function

Tags: gr.group-theory, amenability, pr.probability

Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a group and $\phi:G\rightarrow\mathbb R$ bounded. Let me say that the pair $(G,\phi)$ is amenable if there is a finitely additive probability measure $\mu$ on $G$ such that for all $y\in G$

$$
\int \phi(x)d\mu(x)=\int \phi(x\cdot y)d\mu(x)=\int\phi(y\cdot x)d\mu(x)
$$

> **Question:** Does there exist a non-amenable group such that the pair $(G,\phi)$ is amenable for all $\phi\in\ell^\infty(G)$?

Comment: How about the free group with 2 generators?

Comment: I have no idea. Is it trivial that for any $\phi$ there is such a measure?

Comment: Did you try any $\phi$ at all? 

Comment: No.. Actually I don't know the answer with $\mathbb F_2$. I have some trouble even when $\phi$ is finitely supported. In this case $\mu$ should be such that every finite set has zero measure, but I am not able to contruct (ot to prove the existence) of such a measure in a non-amenable group.

Comment: There are ergodic theorems for free group actions (Bufetov, Alexander I.
Convergence of spherical averages for actions of free groups. 
Ann. of Math. (2) 155 (2002), no. 3, 929–944.) Perhaps that can help. But I would suggest that you ask the simplest question for which you do not know the answer first. How about the indicator function of a generator? 

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Do you know the answer about the indicator function of a generator? I can't see any new real information respect to the indicator function of a point or even repect to a finitely supported function.

Comment: I think you should try to consider the indicator case yourself. It should be an easy exercise. Then you will get an idea what to do next. 

Comment: Well, take a copy of $\mathbb Z$ inside $\mathbb F_2$ and define $\mu$ on $\mathbb F_2$ to be the trivial extension of an invariant mean on this copy of $\mathbb Z$. This is a measure on $\mathbb F_2$ which is null on every finite set. It follows that it is OK for all finitely supported $\phi$. Doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, no such non-amenable group can exist. It follows from Justin Moore's answer to his own [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60247/when-is-non-amenablity-witnessed-by-a-single-non-measurable-set) that a single characteristic function can witness the non-amenability of a group.

Comment: many thanks for the link. I will try to get into the details tomorrow.